# The cut vector by changing the parameters using OGR

Tags: python, ogr, ogr2ogr

I have cut_test_puzzle.shp and kontur.shp https://yadi.sk/d/-5c6s9VX3HEwYY

layer of the cut_test_puzzle.shp has some intersection with each other, is the zorder on a field that identifies the object above and below
[image]
I wrote a bit of code where select the object where №KONTUR and MAX(ZORDER) cuts the other objects that it crosses the circuit

```
import gdal,gdalconst,ogr
from gdalconst import *
import sys, math, time, os
from progressbar import *
import ogrinfo
import string

tabshp1 = raw_input('puzzle : ')
tabshp2 = raw_input('kontur : ')
ogr2ogr = 'C:\\SAT\\python\\ogr2ogr.exe'

layerpuzzle = tabshp1
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
ds=driver.Open(layerpuzzle, 0)
print 'Opened %s' % (layerpuzzle)
inputLayerRelease=ds.GetLayer()  
featureCount = inputLayerRelease.GetFeatureCount() 
print "Number of features in %s: %d" % (os.path.basename(layerpuzzle),featureCount)

fn = tabshp2
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
dataSource = driver.Open(fn, 0)
print 'Opened %s' % (fn)
release_kontur = dataSource.GetLayer()
featureCount_kontur = release_kontur.GetFeatureCount()
print "Number of features in %s: %d" % (os.path.basename(fn),featureCount_kontur)
path = string.split(tabshp1, '\\')
print path[0] +'\\'+ path[1] +'\\'+ path[2] +'\\'+ path[3] +'\\temp'

temp =  path[0] +'\\'+ path[1] +'\\'+ path[2] +'\\'+ path[3] +'\\temp' 
folder = path[0] +'\\'+ path[1] +'\\'+ path[2] +'\\'+ path[3]
rnum = 'cut_test'

temp = path[0] +'\\'+ path[1] +'\\'+ path[2] +'\\temp'
os.makedirs(temp)

print "Start spatial analyst tool"
pbar = ProgressBar(widgets=[Bar('=', '[', ']'), ' ', Counter(), ' of ' + str(int(featureCount)), ' ', ETA()]).start()
pbar.maxval = int(featureCount)



my_file = open(temp+'\\'+'virtual_layer.vrt', 'w')

puzzle = '_puzzle.shp'

kontur = '_kontur.shp'

text_for_file = '<OGRVRTDataSource>' + '\n'\
'\t'    '<OGRVRTlayer name="'+ rnum + '_puzzle">' + '\n'\
'\t''\t'        '<SrcDataSource>' + folder + '</SrcDataSource>' + '\n'\
'\t'    '</OGRVRTlayer>' + '\n'\
'\t'    '<OGRVRTlayer name="mx_zorder">' + '\n'\
'\t''\t'        '<SrcDataSource>' + temp + '\mx_zorder.shp</SrcDataSource>' + '\n'\
'\t'    '</OGRVRTlayer>' + '\n'\
    '</OGRVRTDataSource>'
my_file.write(text_for_file)

my_file.close()

for feat_kontur in release_kontur:
    attribute1 = feat_kontur.GetField('kontur')

    while featureCount > 0 :

        try:
            #  select empty z_up write him in other_zorder

            os.system(ogr2ogr + ' ' + temp + '\\other_zorder.shp' + ' ' + tabshp1 + \
                    ' -sql "SELECT * FROM ' + rnum + '_puzzle WHERE kontur = ''\''+ attribute1 +'\' and z_up is null "')
            # ogr2ogr -sql "SELECT * FROM r_99011_puzzle WHERE z_up is null and kontur = '1' " 
            # select MAX(zorder) from other_zorder


            os.system(ogr2ogr + ' ' + temp + '\\mx_zorder.shp' + ' ' + temp + '\\other_zorder.shp'\
                    ' -dialect SQLITE -sql "SELECT max(zorder) as zorder,* FROM other_zorder"')

            # z_up = zorder
            command = ['',temp + '\\mx_zorder.shp','-dialect','SQLite','-sql','UPDATE mx_zorder SET z_up = zorder','-q'] 
            ogrinfo.main(command) 
            # cut zorder us puzzle
            os.system(ogr2ogr + ' ' + temp + '\\result.shp' + ' ' + temp + '\\virtual_layer.vrt' \
                    ' -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT ST_Difference(g1.geometry,g2.geometry) AS geometry,* FROM ' + rnum + \
                    '_puzzle AS g1, mx_zorder AS g2"') 

            # delete where geometry is null
            os.system(ogr2ogr + ' ' + temp + '\\not_null_geomrtry.shp' + ' ' + temp + '\\result.shp' \
                    ' -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT ST_Buffer( geometry , 0 ),* from result where geometry is not null"') 
            os.system(ogr2ogr + ' ' + temp + '\\not_null_geomrtry.shp' + ' ' + temp + '\\mx_zorder.shp' \
                    ' -append -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT * FROM mx_zorder"') 
            os.system(ogr2ogr + ' ' + tabshp1 + ' ' + temp + '\\not_null_geomrtry.shp' \
                    ' -overwrite')
            featureCount -= 1
            pbar.update(pbar.currval+1)

        except :    
            break   

pbar.finish()
```

the script works but it remains only a couple of sites and it completes, if you look at the result, it will not cut objects

I put all the files in a folder and gave a link to, the only thing you need to specify the path to ogr2ogr although if you are afraid to run unknown files that you can implement this SQL or Python PLEASE HELP!!!